# setVariableData to assign a Invoke Input Variable Collection from java embedding

Tags: java, arrays, embedding, bpel, assign

I am using the below line in JAVA Embedding to assign value to a BPEL Invoke DB adapter input variable.

```
setVariableData("S2C_insert_InputVariable","TmpInvStoc3Collection","/ns8:TmpInvStoc3Collection/ns8:TmpInvStoc3/ns8:batchid","12345");
```

Now i want to put this statement in a while loop within java and want to repeat this for n iterations.  I want to place a loop variable in the collection but I dont know how to do this.

I am looking for something like below.

```
setVariableData("S2C_insert_InputVariable","TmpInvStoc3Collection","/ns8:TmpInvStoc3Collection/ns8:TmpInvStoc3[$loop_variable]/ns8:batchid","12345");
```

Please let me know how to achieve this

Regards
Murali

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the assumption that `value` is a function of `i` and cannot be calculated in the BPEL.

```
String qry = "";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    value = SomeFunctionThatRequiresJavaRatherThanBPEL(i);
    qry = "/ns8:TmpInvStoc3Collection/ns8:TmpInvStoc3[" + i + "]/ns8:batchid";
    setVariableData("S2C_insert_InputVariable","TmpInvStoc3Collection",qry,value);
}
```

The code could be more efficient but it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Dan. This worked, but a small issue. The TmpInvStoc3Collection contains only one TmpInvStoc3 element and i am getting selection failure exception in the second iteration. Is there any way to keep adding TmpInvStoc3 element from java to the S2C_Insert_InputVariable? Thanks a lot

Comment: In a BPEL assign you have the option to automatically add the empty elements. I'm not sure how to reproduce that functionality in Java though.